# Can we change the UI of Chatter?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, chatter, chatter-feed

Can we change the UI, Colors, alignment of Chatter feed?
Posts, comments?

The way it's laid out is very confusing for my users, and we want to divide posts, change color scheme, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify these components. for any customization, you would need to create yours from scratch.

If you do, you can use the [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) which can help you achieve many of functionalities available in these components through Apex.